# Missing ToRecipients data with GraphAPI

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API and cannot get the Recipients address if emailid is external to the company. Is there any special permission that I need to add for that?

```
graphClient.Users[userEmail].MailFolders[folder.Id].Messages.GetAsync
```

When I get messages with these details always the message.ToRecipients[0].EmailAddress.Address  this will be missing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Phani.